# Should good questions with good, and evolving answers be closed because they may attract bad answers? Or only if they have attracted bad answers?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, closed-questions

As a learner in search of answers I am frequently frustrated when I find my exact question on StackExchange but it only contains outdated or incomplete answers because someone(usually outside the specific tagged community) closed it as off topic.

I refer specifically to this old closed but still very relevant question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643950/alternative-editors-ides-for-arduino

This is a prototypical question asked by any arduino beginner advancing to intermediate skill and beyond.  "What are my options?"  The answers are the best I've seen anywhere on the internet, but they are becoming stale as new options emerge.  Of course someone can ask a new similar question to get the current answers, but then the info gets diluted.  If it were open, the relevant new answers would float to the top, noise wouldn't have a chance against the existing upvotes.

It is a popular question, with popular well crafted answers.  It needs new well crafted answers.
It has not started a religious war, though it looks like the sort that could.
What good purpose was suited by its closure?

I cannot fault the closer according to the letter of his reason.  But this reason too often stifles good information in developing fields that require a little discussion to discover the correct answer.  An answer that may not have been known anywhere prior to the parties coming together here.

Fields that target beginners are disproportionately targeted for closure by outsiders because the questions that beginners most need answered often look similar in form to "tabs vs. spaces" type wars, but they still need to be answered.

A question edit would not help the referenced question because it is already clear.
While it does ask to find a tool, the question is not off topic.  The answers are not off topic, the question just fits a predetermined profile targeted for closure.

The purpose of this question is to discuss whether the voting system is sufficient to filter appearance of certain potentially troublesome 'off topic' Q's and A's vs. active closure.  And whether emerging fields, and beginner targeted fields should be given a little bit more latitude in the direction of 'discussion'.

Comment: That's not in any way a *good* question. Actually, it's the prototypical shite list-question which got out of hand too fast.

Comment: Here ya go. https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-Arduino-IDE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions that meet the closure criteria should be closed, yes.

If the community feels that they contain useful content, despite not meeting the site's guidelines, they there is no need to *delete* them.

SO of course doesn't intend to be everything to everyone, there are simply certain types of questions that it has determined it can't (or doesn't want to) support on the site.  If you feel that a question that doesn't belong on SO is a good question, then by all means look for a place where it *is* appropriate in order to ask it (whether that be another site on the SE network, or a site outside the network).

Comment: Based on the number of views and votes, the Arduino community apparently considers it useful content.  As it isn't being deleted, what purpose is served by not allowing it to be updated with new answers?    Judging by Deduplicator's response, SO disagrees.  So, what harm is there in allowing these questions to be answered?  That is not rhetorical, I'm really asking.  No one is forced to answer.

Comment: @slomobile Considering the number of votes I think it's pretty fair to say the community *doesn't* consider it useful.  It has *very* few votes on it, for its view count.

Comment: @slomobile: "*Based on the number of views and votes, the Arduino community apparently considers it useful content.*" Irrelevant. A bad question is a bad question regardless of how much people vote for it. "*So, what harm is there in allowing these questions to be answered?*" It encourages further such questions, which we very much do not want. Exceptions disprove the rule.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas thank you.  That makes sense, I respect that.  Yet a problem exists that beginners trying to enter the community have these questions. They are not unreasonable or bad, even if they are not desired by SO.  SO search results rank at the top, so beginners want to be a part of SO community but are often treated rudely for their ignorance.  Is there a better label to apply to these types of question besides bad, and off topic.  Perhaps "inappropriate for forum" would be a more apt description that does not hurt the feelings of people just looking to learn and contribute.

Comment: @slomobile Nobody did post on that question saying it was "bad", it was simply closed, indicating that it's off topic, which it is.

Comment: @Servy correct.  Only here in Meta was it called bad.  You commented that "the community doesn't consider it useful".  Yet I have first hand personal knowledge of over a dozen Arduino users that used that post as a jumping off point for learning more advanced coding practices and 8 are now professional developers at least partially due to it.  Some people in Meta are a little too eager to assume they speak for "the community" yet fail to consider the community from which the questions are drawn.

Comment: @slomobile if you want software recommendations, there is actually an SE network site for that. Also for arduino stuff specifically. Not everything belongs on SO.

Comment: @slomobile the main issue I see you have is "but newbies HAVE THESE QUESTIONS".... while I agree 100%, I will counter with "Why do they have to ask it here?". Stack is a community, and like any other community, it's the responsibility of the person joining the community to check the rules and conventions, and make sure to abide by them. The choices for off and on-topicness aren't random. I won`t argue about if it's good, bad, useful or not. Stack is NOT the right place for this, period. Why does EVERYTHING computer related have to be hosted on Stack?

Comment: If you like this post, turn it into a blog post and turn THAT into the reference.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So there is!  I'm feeling very foolish about now.  I'd delete this question now if I could.  But an answer has already been upvoted.

Comment: @slomobile Of course the question you linked to would merit closure on that site as well, because it doesn't even come close to meeting their criteria for an acceptable question.

Comment: @Patrice You are completely correct.  "Why do they have to ask it here?"  Because the best answers they get when Googling their questions come from here.  That is how I ended up here.  You are a victim of your own success SO.  Perhaps the software recommendations site could be linked in close reasons like this.  Any comments on  "inappropriate for forum" vs. "off-topic"?

Comment: @slomobile So do you go to your coffee shop to ask them to change their oil because they make great coffee?  The fact that some place offers one service, and does it well, doesn't obligate them to offer every other service that you want.

Comment: @slomobile If someone is going to get offended when their told that their question is "off topic" when it's off topic, then there is nothing that will satisfy them; they're so out to be offended that there is no way for you to possibly do something they would consider appropriate.  "Off topic" is an entirely acceptable, and polite, term to describe something that is off topic somewhere.

Comment: @slomobile yeah, I did the same. I learned to Google that got me to SO, then went "hey, that's a GREAT site. I wonder how I can PROPERLY join the community". Then I did the research, learned the rules, followed them. When I made mistakes, I never blamed SO for it. I didn't learn SO's rules, and THAT'S ON ME. Could they be clearer? yeah, very likely. friendlier? yes, 100%. Does it mean it's NOT my responsibility to learn them? not at all. It is still on the user to learn them. Yes SO is a victim of it's success... doesn't excuse people who don't check the rules, as so many before them did.

Comment: @Servy  That analogy doesn't quite hold water because my coffee shop doesn't have cars inside getting their oil changed.  Anyone can go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643950/alternative-editors-ides-for-arduino and see their neighbor getting oil changed through the window.  I understand that is not the message you want out there, but it is out there.  And it is there because both the questioners and answerers volunteered their time to put it there.  They feel as much a part of SO as you do, rightly or not.

Comment: @Patrice  I hope it doesn't appear that I am blaming SO for anything.  That was far from my intent.  The referenced page didn't either.  I know the rules, at least I read and interpreted them as best I could.  Your understanding may not be the same as mine.  I came here to understand why the rules are what they are and have a discussion about how to avoid disenfranchising a segment of the SO community.  That is how an open voluntary society moves itself forward.  I thought Meta is the place where that work is done.  Am I wrong?

Comment: @slomobile so your interpretation of "no software recommendation questions" is.... "software recommendation questions are okay"? How is that interpreting?  And that question is CLEARLY marked as "off-topic" and "closed". It's not like your neighbor is getting his oil changed. It's more like you see the neighbor getting told "you shouldn't have this here" about his oil.... so..... seriously, what do you expect?

Comment: @slomobile meta IS the proper place, 100%.. But even there you should make research, understand a bit more. Right now you don't really have an argument to keep the question besides "but people look at it".... which isn't really a reason to keep something we say we don't allow

Comment: @Patrice You misunderstood me.  I was referring to jonrsharpe's recommendation for the SE network site Software Recommendations.  If someone asks for an inappropriate software recommendation, close the question, but in the close notes, refer them to that SE Site to get those kind of questions off of SO.  Note in my original question, I never asked to have the question reopened.  I said I cannot fault the close reason.  Read last paragraph of question.  I know it is against the rules.  I was asking for a discussion to see if anyone thought there might be reason to ammend the rules.  Guess not.

Comment: The question IS "CLEARLY marked as "off-topic" and "closed"", in a relatively small box compared to the rest of the page full of information that is gold to people who are actively seeking that page out 4 years after it was closed.  To those people, the closed message is just noise.  Its like a coffee shop with a nice cake display in the window and a small sign that says "don't come here for cake".  And you are the waitress that gets upset when people keep ordering cake.  If you want these messages off SO, move them to a more appropriate SE site.  BTW, who is SO?  Am I?

Comment: @slomobile If you're arguing for the deletion of that quesiton, you just might get your wish.  Oh, and as for the closure being unclear, it's also marked as closed in the question title, which is the single most visible aspect of the question (on, but especially off, of the question itself).

Comment: @slomobile but that question wouldnt fly on soft rec as i understand their help center.... So not sure why putting it there would help. Well you keep on thinking we should keep thos question evem if it's off topic. Which means you may understand the rule, but not its reasoning. And the "close" may be noise to THEM. it goes back to the fact it's their responsibility to learn the site. It doesnt make it less clearly indicated.

Comment: and to address your last paragraph : no. Active closure is needed for this. We judge questions on the question. Not on the answers it gets. Saying "yeah it COULD attract bad answers... It just doesnt now" is in no way a reason to keep a question opened. And letting "beginners" have special rules will make it IMPOSSIBLE to enforce our quality standards, as people will just mark off topic question as "im a beginner" and ask for whatever kind of crap they feel like

Comment: I'm not arguing for that question or against it.  I just chose it as an example of a question that is very much on topic for the people that seek it out, yet clearly off topic according to SO rules.  It has some value.  I'd like to see its value increase, but it sounds like that won't happen here.  Human nature is such that we will keep coming back for something we want wherever it is we see it, regardless of closed signs.   If truly off topic, it should not be visible on SO lest it attract others, as per your argument.  If it is to remain, get the most value from it.

Comment: I accepted the only answer provided, though Patrice was equally helpful.  I noticed a mistake in my original question that drew many astray.  When I said "While it does ask to find a tool, the question is not off topic."  I meant to continue ..."not off topic for the people who google this question 4 years later."  It was a good question for those that found it,  and needed its answers, despite being a "bad" fit for SO.

Comment: That doesn't mean it's not off-topic.  It's still off-topic, but since it's still somewhat useful, it's not deleted yet.

Comment: @fbueckert Don't mistake not having come to the attention of enough people having the ability (and enough of it) and retaining the motivation to properly moderate with being in any way acceptable or useful. (Because it came to peoples attention, it already gained 5 of the 8 needed delete-votes, a number which is in general ridiculously hard to get.)